# How to interact Users(input form data) Using Salesforce Sites into the SalesForce Application(to Custom objects)

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com, salesforce-service-cloud

First of all I'm really sorry if i'm asking a Dumb Question. But unfortunately i can't find out a way to take inputs for my salesforce Application.
**I am developing a simple CV Management app, but i can't figure out how to interact users(input data) to the App? I have created Candidate Custom object, and manually i can create the Candidates, but my requirement is to create records by Candidates themselves.**

I followed SalesForce Tutorials and i found out a way to display data using VisualForce Custom Pages. But what i want to## Heading ## do is when i giving a link to the user, he can go to that link and there having form to fill with his personal data, and submit only. But i'm just confused how to user input data map with our Custom Candidate object fields. 
when i'm searching i saw some FormAssembly and Custom VisualForce Pages. But Problem is I don't hope to use any 3rd party apps.

**Tutorials says that;**

> In the past, to make Force.com data available to the general public, you had to set up a Web
>   server, create custom Web pages (JSP, PHP, or other), and use the API to integrate Force.com
>   apps with an external website. This is no longer the case, thanks to Sites!

Please if you can, help me Friends, Really Appreciate it & Thank you soo much..

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to do something along these lines...

1. Create a Visualforce page with standard controller set to your custom object which is the "CV Entry" page (to send candidates to)
2. Create a Force.com site in your salesforce org to allow public or restricted access to the page
3. Setup page authentication/permissions as required